# Adjustment of method to remove record creation

Tags: apex

Morning all,

I've been pulling my hair out trying to resolve this issue but am not reaching a solution so I am reaching out to you, the Hive Mind, for assistance.

I've co-opted some logic I found to automatically associate an Opportunity to a Case when it is inserted using an external ID via Jitterbit. It is working as I expected, but with an addition unintended consequence.As you'll see from below, when the Opp is inserted, if it does not find a Case to associate to, it creates one.

I hold my hands up that this is quite a rookie mistake, it's pretty obvious now that I look back at it, but I'm running out of time to resolve. Can anyone recommend adjustments to the below?

Class:

```
   public static void updateOpportunityOnCases (List<Opportunity> scope) {

    List<Opportunity> opps = (List<Opportunity>) scope;

    Set<String> ERPref = new Set<String>();
        for (Opportunity o : opps) {
        ERPref.add(o.External_Quote_Id__c);
        }

    Map<String, Case> Cases = new Map<String, Case>();
        for (Case c : [select Id, External_Quote_Id__c from Case where External_Quote_Id__c in :ERPref]) {
            Cases.put(c.External_Quote_Id__c, c);
        }

        for (Opportunity o : opps) {
            Case c; 
            if (Cases.containsKey(o.External_Quote_Id__c)) {
                c = Cases.get(o.External_Quote_Id__c);
            } else {
            c = new Case(External_Quote_Id__c = o.External_Quote_Id__c);
            Cases.put(o.External_Quote_Id__c, c);
            }

        c.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
        }
upsert Cases.values();

}
```

It's called from an After Insert trigger.

As a second ask, I also want to update the Opportunity that has been inserted with the Case Id (I have a lookup on each object referencing the other). Can I update both records from within the same class?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I wasn't editing out enough of the ELSE statement. I'll move the second question to another post.

```
public static void updateOpportunityOnCases (List<Opportunity> scope) {

    List<Opportunity> opps = (List<Opportunity>) scope;

    Set<String> ERPref = new Set<String>();
        for (Opportunity o : opps) {
        ERPref.add(o.External_Quote_Id__c);
        }

    Map<String, Case> Cases = new Map<String, Case>();
        for (Case c : [select Id, External_Quote_Id__c from Case where External_Quote_Id__c in :ERPref]) {
            Cases.put(c.External_Quote_Id__c, c);
        }

        for (Opportunity o : opps) {
            Case c; 
            if (Cases.containsKey(o.External_Quote_Id__c)) {
                c = Cases.get(o.External_Quote_Id__c);
            //} else {
            //c = new Case(External_Quote_Id__c = o.External_Quote_Id__c);
            //Cases.put(o.External_Quote_Id__c, c);
            }

        c.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
        }
upsert Cases.values();

}
```